# Grep for image URLs

Tags: javascript, regex, grep

I want to search for and list all image URLs in a (or multiple) HTML pages. Using Regexr.com I was able to put together this regular expression: `src=".*(\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif)"` which works fine *on* [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/3kai1), but not on the command line. The above regular expression gets zero results when I run `grep -o 'src=".*(\.png|\.jpg)' index.html` Is this a difference between javascript regular expressions and grep regular expressions that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Your regex pattern looks a poor choice for matching image URLs.  For one thing, it would be matching anything ending with an image extension, including things which aren't really URLs.  Maybe show us the JavaScript code and some actual data.

Comment: Try `src=".*?(?:\.png|\.jpeg|\.jpg)`

Comment: don't use RegExp to parse HTML, use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `grep` uses an older, less powerful regex engine. Using the `egrep` variant will give you very similar behavior to what JavaScript provides.

This pattern worked for me (adjusting your original `grep`):

```
egrep -o 'src=".*(\.png|\.jpg)' index.html
```

Or (better), just use the `-E` flag:

```
grep -E -o 'src=".*(\.png|\.jpg)' index.html
```

From [another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17951/127916):

> -E switches grep into a special mode so that the expression is evaluated as an ERE (Extended Regular Expression) as opposed to its
>   normal pattern matching

[linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/1/egrep):

> -E, --extended-regexp Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below). (-E is specified by POSIX .)